# Bash can't find makepkg on server

Tags: linux, bash, archlinux, pacman-package-manager

I'm currently running into an issue where I am not able to use makepkg on my server.

I've verified that pacman is installed correctly so I'm assuming this has to have something to do with my environment PATH?

Trying to run makepkg from my bash prompt I just get

```
-bash: makepkg: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need the correct path of command...
Try exec echo in $PATH and try export the path command to $PATH.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/of/command
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling pacman, like so: `sudo pacman -S pacman`